# Monitor auto-detect Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, graphics, display, gdm

I am currently running Ubuntu 15.04 on my desktop machine with two monitors attached. One monitor is NOT directly connected to my machine but wired through a HDMI-switch (so I can connect my PS4 or Raspberry to the screen without any cable mess).

Now there seems to be an issue with this setup. Booting up my machine gives me my login prompt on both my screens (well expanded two both screens). If I start my PS4 the HDMI-switch changes to its input automatically (as expected). If I manually select the port connected to my Linux machine the screen remains blank.

I assume it is a software related issue since a restart of gdm (I am running gnome) makes me lose my session but gives me an image on both screens.
I tried to do the switching during boot (Turn on PC - turn on PS4 and quickly change back to PC input) --> image on both screens. I also don't seem to have a 'detect monitors' button in my display settings.

My current specs:

- Ubuntu 15.04 - gnome as desktop environment
- HD 5770 - AMD prop. driver
- Displays connected via DP and HDMI

Restarting gdm is not a long term solution in my opinion.

Comment: It is actually running right now. I cannot say what ultimately solved it but purging the amd-driver and X-server and reinstalling X-server afterwards seemed to solve it. So I guess it was a driver related issue but I have nothing to further back up this guess.